# Bootstrap fixed navbar disappears on iOS inertia scrolling, then reappars on stop

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, uiwebview

I noticed that when I inertia scroll my webpage within a WebView on ios, the fixed navbar disappears...and then when the scrolling stops, the navbar reappears.

I assumed that a fixed navbar would stay fixed and visible all the time.  I already tried disabling the inertia scroll by adding *-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;* to my body element, but that did not change the scrolling at all so it did not fix the disappearing.

When I viewed/scrolled my website within Safari, the navbar stayed visible all the time.

Conclusion is, it has to do with webview controller and maybe some property that needs to be set.

I will search stack for that, but in the meantime, if anyone has ideas on how to prevent this please let me know.

All help/feedback is appreciated.

**Update**: Reading other posts, this may be an iOS11 issue.  Now that I think about it, the webview worked fine until recent update.  I will update question if solution found.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be with UIWebView. 
Using WKWebkit fixed the issue for me as it is the apple recommended view for web content since the update.